# How to reliably parse the output of git config --list?

Tags: python, bash, git, config, git-config

I'm trying to parse the output of `git config --list` to get a list of key/value pairs. For simple variables like `user.name` e.g.

```
user.name=John Doe
```

it seems like I can just split the line on `'='` to get the key and value. However, after looking into the [syntax](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_syntax), it appears that a key can contain any value in a subsection (including `'='`), and a value can contain a `'='` or a `'.'`. So how do I reliably parse the output of `git config --list` to get key/value pairs?

Also, I wonder if running `git -c key=value <comecommand>` will always work with key/value containing `'='` or `'.'`.

Comment: Seems like a regexp could capture the first equal sign, regardless of other occurrences in the value.

Comment: @planet `=` cannot be contained by a key. Try it yourself in your own configuration file ;)

Comment: If you can use a command besides `git config --list`, then you can get all keys from `git config --name-only --list`, and each key's value from `git config --get-all {key}`

Comment: @Ulysse did you read the documentation page I linked? `Subsection names are case sensitive and can contain any characters except newline and the null byte. `

Answer (score 0):

If you  have Bash4+ you can parse `key=value` pairs from the git config into an associative array:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A git_config

# Parse git config into an associative array
while IFS='=' read -r k v; do
  git_config["$k"]="$v"
done < <(git config --list)

# Print-out of the parsed config

printf '%-40s %s\n' 'Git config keys' 'Values'
printf '=%.0s' {1..120}
echo
for k in "${!git_config[@]}"; do
  printf '%-40q %q\n' "$k" "${git_config["$k"]}"
done
```